# SSRS Calculated Field From Parameter: Possible?

Tags: reporting-services

Let's say I have a field:

```
Person
```

A `Person` can belong to a group, selected by the user, at Runtime:

```
"Group 1"    or    "Group 2"
```

In SSRS, each of those would be a multi-select dropdown.  I would like to be able to group people based on group in the generated report.  However, I can't seem to figure out a way to do this....  I literally have no ideas.  Is it possible?

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok! Figured it out, in case someone else needs to know.

There is no way to do this in the `Data` section.  The key is to go to layout, and add a group there.  That lets you use advanced expressions, such as: `Parameters!Group1.Value`, etc.  Also the expressions that it lets you use are different from the expressions that you can use on the `Data` screen.  For example `IN` no longer works, and `FIND` becomes `INSTR`.  It really is confusing that this isn't consistent.

In any case, with the ability to use expressions with the parameters, everything else is trivial... Thanks!